# Sort numbers with minimum comparison

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, sorting

We have 6 balls of 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 grams. How to find each one's weight using a 2 sides balance (a side can take many balls).

Comment: Is there any criterion? Do we only get a limited number of weighings or something? Because a bubble sort is simple, and fast enough with this few balls (only $15$ weighings, and I think the theoretical minimum is $9$, so it's not bad).

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your answer. Yes the goal is to find the minimum number of weighings. The theoretical minimum is 10 for sorting algorithms of 6 elements. This is a rather specific case and I wonder if we can't do it in less.

Comment: I misspoke. The theoretical minimum is $6$, actually. The idea is this: There are $720$ different possibilities. For each weighing, there are three outcomes: either one side is heavier, or the other side is heavier, or they are in balance. That means that if we're clever about how we lay up the balls, we may be able to narrow it down to $240$ different possibilities with one weighing. Once more, and we can narrow it down to $80$ different possibilities. And so on. Whether there actually _is_ such an optimal strategy, I don't know.

Comment: Can you develop more on how you get these numbers and what method to follow to implement the strategy?

Comment: And why 6 is the minimum when decreasing the different possibilities by weighing?

Comment: I have no how to use this to implement a strategy other than to check that a strategy is, in fact, optimal. The count is six because the first weighing takes you down to 240 possibilities. The second weighing takes you to 80. The third takes you to either 26 or 27. The fourth to either 8 or 9. The fifth takes you to 2 or 3 possibilities, and lastly, a final weighing to decide between them. Now, I would actually be surprised if such an algorithm existed, and at the very least, it would be very messy to use. But there you have it.

Comment: Okay. But the question is to find the feasible method with minimum comparisons (even if more than 6). And prove that we can't do better...